# How often does Azure change its baseline browser snapshot / image?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, azure, dllimport

My site is hosted on Azure. For one of my features, I need to have access to DLL's based on either IE8 or IE9 (for the IEGetProtectedModeCookie function in ieframe.dll). This method was introduced with IE8.

Unfortunately, Azure is currently based on an image that uses IE7, so when I try to call this method I get a "DLL entry point not found" exception.

I've tried everything I can think of to get the x64 version of this DLL on to my Azure instance, but haven't had any luck. So for the time being, for one of my scenarios I'm not going to support browsers based on IE8. Instead, I'll just wait patiently until Azure is based on a browser snapshot or image that uses either IE8 or IE9.

How long do you think I'll have to wait?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step-by-step guide to automatically installing IE9 on Azure instances.

We do this in our Worker Roles for a similar reason. Works fine.

http://sajojacob.com/blog/2011/03/startup-tasks-elevated-privileges-vm-role/

Comment: +1 A startup task should do the trick, and make it work even as Armchair Bronco dynamically expands the # of instances.

Comment: Marking this as the answer, even though I originally wanted only a guess of the date when this will be available natively. We had so many frustrations trying to get the right DLL's on Azure that we finally said: "Forget it! We'll just wait until all the bits we need are there for free." My co-founder apparently tried installing IE8 (or some IE8 DLL's?) but got an access denied error. If a startup task lets us install IE9 on Azure, then (in theory) all of our problems will be solved. Thanks.

Comment: Wow, based on the blog article above, it seems like we only need to make the following change to the service configuration XML file to get IE8 installed: <ServiceConfiguration ... osFamily="2" osVersion="*" ...> (changing the osFamily from "1" to "2"). The article you linked to described installing IE9 which turns out to be much more involved. The IEGetProtectedModeCookie fn was introduced in IE8, so that may be good enough for us. Thanks again for this tip.

Comment: This worked! We had been on the phone with Azure support for over 2 weeks and couldn't fix the problem. In the end, we just needed to change osFamily from "1" to "2".

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question, presumably Windows Azure VM images will have IE8 (or IE9) when a Windows server OS ships with that version.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a list of [Azure OS's and related SDKs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee924680.aspx)  The dates there should give you an idea.

As an alternative you could create your own VHD and [upload it to Azure.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg465385.aspx)  But then you will be required to maintain the OS patches yourself.